# iOS8 - Custom Keyboard is not pushing previous chat up

Tags: keyboard, ios8

So I am developing a custom keyboard, and I notice that when I test my keyboard on Message app, when I click on the text input area, the keyboard just shows up and did not push the previous chat up which results in the keyboard blocking the latest chats.

If I switch to system keyboard, the previous chats are being pushed up fine, and then I switch to my custom keyboard, sending some texts, all works fine.

I am not sure if this is something that Custom Keyboards have to handle.

Anyone encountered the same issue and maybe have a resolution for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I some times am having the same problem ,the third party keyboard should behave the same as system keyboard in that kid of situation.  maybe it is because the iOS8 beta is very buggy at the moment.

Comment: yeah, looks like this was fixed in beta 5